# Boost.Asio/OpenSSL HTTPS GET certificate trouble

Tags: c++, https, openssl, ssl-certificate, boost-asio

I am using Boost Asio and my goal is to send an HTTPS GET request to www.realmofthemadgod.com. I found some code on GitHub claiming to do that which I've included below but first I'll go through some observations:

- The code fails with an error `sslv3 alert handshake failure`.
- On command line, the command `openssl s_client -connect www.realmofthemadgod.com:443` results in the same error and some other messages about no certificates being available
- However, the command `openssl s_client -connect www.realmofthemadgod.com:443 -servername www.realmofthemadgod.com` does find the correct certificate!

Now, the problem is how do I achieve what the `-servername` switch does, in code.

What I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "libcryptoMD.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libsslMD.lib")

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class client
{
public:
    client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, boost::asio::ssl::context& context, const std::string& server, const std::string& path)
        : resolver_(io_service), socket_(io_service, context)
    {
        // Form the request. We specify the "Connection: close" header so that the
        // server will close the socket after transmitting the response. This will
        // allow us to treat all data up until the EOF as the content.
        std::ostream request_stream(&request_);
        request_stream << "GET " << path << " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        request_stream << "Host: " << server << "\r\n";
        request_stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
        request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

        // Start an asynchronous resolve to translate the server and service names
        // into a list of endpoints.
        tcp::resolver::query query(server, "https");
        resolver_.async_resolve(query,
            boost::bind(&client::handle_resolve, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::iterator));
    }

private:

    void handle_resolve(const boost::system::error_code& err,
        tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
    {
        if (!err)
        {
            std::cout << "Resolve OK" << "\n";
            socket_.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer);
            //socket_.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_none);
            socket_.set_verify_callback(
                boost::bind(&client::verify_certificate, this, _1, _2));

            boost::asio::async_connect(socket_.lowest_layer(), endpoint_iterator,
                boost::bind(&client::handle_connect, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Error resolve: " << err.message() << "\n";
        }
    }

    bool verify_certificate(bool preverified,
        boost::asio::ssl::verify_context& ctx)
    {
        // The verify callback can be used to check whether the certificate that is
        // being presented is valid for the peer. For example, RFC 2818 describes
        // the steps involved in doing this for HTTPS. Consult the OpenSSL
        // documentation for more details. Note that the callback is called once
        // for each certificate in the certificate chain, starting from the root
        // certificate authority.

        // In this example we will simply print the certificate's subject name.
        char subject_name[256];
        X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
        X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);
        std::cout << "Verifying " << subject_name << "\n";

        return preverified;
    }

    void handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& err)
    {
        if (!err)
        {
            std::cout << "Connect OK " << "\n";
            socket_.async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client,
                boost::bind(&client::handle_handshake, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Connect failed: " << err.message() << "\n";
        }
    }

    void handle_handshake(const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            std::cout << "Handshake OK " << "\n";
            std::cout << "Request: " << "\n";
            const char* header = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(request_.data());
            std::cout << header << "\n";

            // The handshake was successful. Send the request.
            boost::asio::async_write(socket_, request_,
                boost::bind(&client::handle_write_request, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Handshake failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
        }
    }

    void handle_write_request(const boost::system::error_code& err)
    {
        if (!err)
        {
            // Read the response status line. The response_ streambuf will
            // automatically grow to accommodate the entire line. The growth may be
            // limited by passing a maximum size to the streambuf constructor.
            boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_, response_, "\r\n",
                boost::bind(&client::handle_read_status_line, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Error write req: " << err.message() << "\n";
        }
    }

    void handle_read_status_line(const boost::system::error_code& err)
    {
        if (!err)
        {
            // Check that response is OK.
            std::istream response_stream(&response_);
            std::string http_version;
            response_stream >> http_version;
            unsigned int status_code;
            response_stream >> status_code;
            std::string status_message;
            std::getline(response_stream, status_message);
            if (!response_stream || http_version.substr(0, 5) != "HTTP/")
            {
                std::cout << "Invalid response\n";
                return;
            }
            if (status_code != 200)
            {
                std::cout << "Response returned with status code ";
                std::cout << status_code << "\n";
                return;
            }
            std::cout << "Status code: " << status_code << "\n";

            // Read the response headers, which are terminated by a blank line.
            boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_, response_, "\r\n\r\n",
                boost::bind(&client::handle_read_headers, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Error: " << err.message() << "\n";
        }
    }

    void handle_read_headers(const boost::system::error_code& err)
    {
        if (!err)
        {
            // Process the response headers.
            std::istream response_stream(&response_);
            std::string header;
            while (std::getline(response_stream, header) && header != "\r")
                std::cout << header << "\n";
            std::cout << "\n";

            // Write whatever content we already have to output.
            if (response_.size() > 0)
                std::cout << &response_;

            // Start reading remaining data until EOF.
            boost::asio::async_read(socket_, response_,
                boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
                boost::bind(&client::handle_read_content, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Error: " << err << "\n";
        }
    }

    void handle_read_content(const boost::system::error_code& err)
    {
        if (!err)
        {
            // Write all of the data that has been read so far.
            std::cout << &response_;

            // Continue reading remaining data until EOF.
            boost::asio::async_read(socket_, response_,
                boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
                boost::bind(&client::handle_read_content, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
        else if (err != boost::asio::error::eof)
        {
            std::cout << "Error: " << err << "\n";
        }
    }

    tcp::resolver resolver_;
    boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket_;
    boost::asio::streambuf request_;
    boost::asio::streambuf response_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        //boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
        boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv12);
        ctx.set_default_verify_paths();

        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        client c(io_service, ctx, "www.realmofthemadgod.com", "/");
        io_service.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some digging and learned that the switch `-servername` enables something called server name indication (SNI) and I found a way to enable it in code.

This is added to the `client` constructor:

```
// Set SNI Hostname (many hosts need this to handshake successfully)
if (!SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(stream.native_handle(), host))
{
    boost::system::error_code ec((int)ERR_get_error(), boost::asio::error::get_ssl_category());
    throw boost::system::system_error(ec);
}
```

The code still doesn't quite work (it waits for an async callback to happen and times out) but this solves the original problem presented in the question.